# Laravel 5.4: How to set a first and default parameter to route() function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I 'm passing a prefix parameter to all routes on my webiste:

```
Route::prefix("{param}")->group(function () {
    # code...
});
```

Sometimes I need to call the `route()` function in the views. The problem is there, because I need to pass the `$param` as first parameter like:

resources\views\welcome.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('about-us', $param) }}">About Us</a>
```

The question is: I do not need to pass `$param` in `route()` function because its not necessary. How to avoid this and do just the following:

```
<a href="{{ route('about-us') }}">About Us</a>
```

Is there a way to create a middleware and set a "global" configuration to `route()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using @William Correa approach, I've created a helper function to setting up a prefix parameter to default Laravel function helper `route()`.

app\Helpers\functions.php

```
function routex($route, $params = [])
{
    if (!is_array($params)) {
        $params = [$params];
    }

    // Set the first parameter to App::getLocale()
    array_unshift($params, App::getLocale());
    return route($route, $params);
}
```

Now when I try to get a link to `route()` by name, just use `routex('about-us')` and the `routex()` function will put a prefix parameter like `App::getLocale()` or anything else you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller you can protect your route like this:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

and than

```
Route::get('/about', 'yourcontroller@yourmethod')->name('name');
```

or in your web.php you can declare a group without a prefix like this

```
Route::namespace('name')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/about', 'yourcontroller@yourmethod')->name('name');
});
```

Comment: Yeah! I know I can protect my route by using middlewares. So...its not the question. I need to avoid passing `{param}` to all the controllers from all the routes, cause `{param}` is a prefix from URL. I need the prefix only on my custom middleware I've created and not to controllers/views.

Comment: Than make two groups: 1 group with a prefix and 1 group without a prefix

Comment: Ok. But if I do not pass a prefix parameter, how do my application would know that parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, like this:

```
Route::get('about-us', 'AboutController@getAboutUs')->name('about-us');
```

Now if you call `route('about-us')` it will generate url to .../about-us.

Comment: Sure! But I still need to pass a prefix parameter `{param}` for all the routes. Then I will need to use `$param` in my `route()` function. The question was: How to set the `$param` to every called `route()` functions for all the views even I do not set it like `<a href="{{ route('about-us', $param) }}">Link</a>`?

Its not good to get the `{param}` from all the routes and pass it to controller and then pass `$param` to the view.